# symfony2 get firewall name on login page

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, firewall

I'd want to use a login page to access different firewalls, so I need to get information about the firewall I'm logging in.
In my controller I'd use

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getProviderKey()
```

but as an anonymous user I don't have access to getProviderKey method.
I could also parse

```
_security.xxx.target_path
```

to get xxx firewall but I'm looking for a more general solution if it exists at all.
Any idea?

Comment: Of course, it's due to security; but if you need just `target_path` you can define a separate param in config file and use it in your controller

Comment: I'd need provider key to pilot many different parameters. To be honest I don't understand why anonymous token can't get a provider key. Pages outside firewalls don't have a provider at all, but pages inside firewall, even if anonymously authenticated -let's say a login page- are still under a firewall.

Answer (score 11):

As of symfony 3.2, you can now get the current firewall configuration using the following:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $firewall = $this->container
        ->get('security.firewall.map')
        ->getFirewallConfig($request)
        ->getName();
}
```

Ref: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-firewall-config-class-and-profiler

Comment: Referencing service "security.firewall.map" will no longer work in Symfony 3.4 as the service is not public.

Comment: I get the following: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "The "security.firewall.map" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead." at vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php line 337

Comment: Yep, as of symfony 3.4 you should use proper dependency injection rather than injecting the service container (the Controller class has been deprecated in symfony 4.2, so you'll be forced to wire the services your controller actually needs in 5.0).

Answer (score 2):

For Symfony 3.4 I wrote this to avoid referencing the non-public "security.firewall.map" service:

```
$firewallName = null;
if (($firewallContext = trim($request->attributes->get("_firewall_context", null))) && (false !== ($firewallContextNameSplit = strrpos($firewallContext, ".")))) {
    $firewallName = substr($firewallContext, $firewallContextNameSplit + 1);
}
```

*(Referencing "security.firewall.map" on 3.4 will throw an exception.)*

Edit: This will not work in a custom exception controller function.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing a little research on this myself recently so that I could send this information in an XACML request as part of the environment.

As far as I can tell from GitHub issues like this one:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14435

There is currently no way to reliably get the information out of Symfony except the dirty compiler pass hack suggested on the linked issue. It does appear from the conversation on these issues, they are working on making this available, however, the status is still open, so we will have to be patient and wait for it to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

@Adambean's answer is pretty elegant, but I'd write it as a one-liner:

```
$firewallName = array_slice(explode('.', trim($request->attributes->get('_firewall_context'))), -1)[0];
```

The difference is that `$firewallName` will always be a string (which may be empty).

Also, please note that this answer (like @Adambean's) doesn't work for a firewall with a dot in its name.